# How to send and receive xmls using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to send and recieve xml using Apache Kafka,i am new to kafka and i did not see any documentation on how to send/recieve xml files using kafka, Please redirect me to the good documentation or any sample code which explains me better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send any kind of message you want. The Kafka APIs provide default encoders for string and binary types. Just send the XML as a string and read it as a string on the other end. It's up to you to create, validate, and parse the XML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read about KafkaAvroSerializer to send /recieve  XMLS..but without using it cant we send directly XML to Kafka  instead of String as XML.

Comment: Hi is there anyway you can provide a simple example? It would help a lot. I am new to Kafka as well.